# leave from a zoom in and out method jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a plugin to enlarge images on mouseover or mousedown that was written by Jack Moore http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/ and I am using it after I hide a previous image and add the a second one. I want to return to the first image -either pressing a button option or double click- but I realized whenever the zoom method is called there is no possibility to do something to leave the enlarge functionality.
A simplified version of my code is below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src='jquery.zoom.js'></script>
        <script>
            function changeimg() {
                $("#img1").hide();
                text = "<span id='onclickzoom'>";
                text += "<img src='img2.png' onclick='zoomfunc()' alt='hello'/></span>";
                $("body").append(text);
                zoomfunc();
            }
            function gbf() {
                $('#onclickzoom').remove();
                $("#img1").show();
            }
            function zoomfunc() {
                $('#onclickzoom').zoom({
                    on: 'click'
                }); /*I need to leave in a moment from this method using a button or double click*/
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="img1.png" onclick='changeimg(this)'>
    </body>
</html>
```

The gbf() function is for restoring the first image and I don't know how to call it or leave from this zoom mode.
Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to disable the zoom when restoring the first image?

Comment: Yes, I want to disable it.

Comment: `$('#onclickzoom').unbind('click');` should stop it, but looking at your code I'd expect it to work already since you never call `zoom` on the image?

Comment: zoom is called in the zoomfunc() function and this function is called from changeimg() one.
Please let me know where I could put the command that you gave me.

Comment: Can you try and describe your problem again? Is there an issue with the first image or the one inside the span?

Comment: The only problem I have is I can't leave from the enlarge option that is executed in the zoomfunc(). No, there isn't an issue with any image.

Comment: Hey Matt, It worked. Thank you so much my friend.